# Is it possible to connect several servers with identical IP addresses and manually manage the ARP cache in order to communicate with them?

Tags: networking, network-programming, arp

Let's say I want to perform automated setup on several servers at the same time. So I connect 10 servers to my network at the same time, each one comes with a default IP of 192.168.1.1 but I have the list of each of their MAC addresses.

Now if I want to iterate through the MAC addresses and send a packet to each one of these machines by manually updating the ARP entry, will that work? What if my central router is also located at 192.168.1.1? Are the packets going to make it to their destination?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are located in the same subnet as the servers, this should work. The router is no different, since it is just another host in the network. As long as you have a static ARP entry for the server you want to communicate with, ARP requests should not be sent, and no conflict should arise.

If, however, you are located at a different subnet from the servers, this would be more difficult, as you would have an ARP entry only for the gateway which leads you to their subnet, and that router will have to be one to switch entries to direct you to the correct server.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in the same LAN. You need to consider:

- Servers with same IP address in the same LAN could detect duplicate IP address and generate a problem
- When sending packets to other networks through the router your application needs to know the MAC address of the router.
- There could be other applications in the client system that might send ARP requests updating you ARP cache in the middle of your application process and that could make your strategy fail